# Replace from array with other array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

How can I replace arrays from other arrays?

My code:

```
foreach($item_name[1] as $index => $text_to_draw) {
    $y_pos = $position_text_array[$index];
    $color_text = $color_array[$index];
    imagettftext($image, 10, 0, $x_pos, $y_pos, $color_text, $font, $text_to_draw);
}
```

The result of `$text_to_draw` need to be replace if a array is on the list:

```
$text_replace = array(
    "Nice" => "Bad",
    "Beautiful" => "Nice",
    "Fish" => "Dog",
    "Cat" => "Mouse",
);
```

I want it like:

```
$text_to_draw = "Cat, Facebook, Fire";
```

Then the output should be:

> Mouse, Facebook, Fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_replace()` accepts arrays:

```
$output = str_replace(array_keys($text_replace), $text_replace, $text_to_draw);
```

- Search for the array keys
- Replace with the array values